# `Periodogram` returning only 1/0 error

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have a large dataset and would like to get a `Periodogram` (I saved the data as `CloudObject`):

```
a = CloudGet[
  "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/80bbf4ba-7f4c-4a8c-889f-0eaa7be029f9"];
Periodogram[a, SampleRate -> Automatic]
```

I get bunch of

[image]

and not plot and all variables are reset from memory. Why is it behaving as such? Is there a way around to actually get the plot?

Comment: I get a `CloudGet::notperm: Unable to perform the requested operation. Permission denied.` when trying to fetch the data.

Comment: I get the same warning as mentioned by @Hbar. Can you reproduce the issue with a simpler sample that can be posted in this site?

Comment: @xzczd Could you try now, I set the permissions to public which hopefully solves the issue.

Comment: Periodogram[a[[All, 2]]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Periodogram` appears to take a rank-1 list, not a list of lists like your data in `a` .

This simple example will also fail the same way:

```
Periodogram[Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 10, 0.6}]
```

... and you'll get a division by zero error.

You want to do this instead:

```
Periodogram[a[[All, 2]]]
```